# OSX: Why does an uninstalled program ask for inbound connections on login? How do I fix this?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, firewall, uninstall

I uninstalled an application using AppZapper called PdaNet.  It is a tethering application for my phone.

Now every time I login, I am asked if I would like to allow inboud connections from PdaNet by the firewall.

A search for PdaNet with spotlight does not return any results.

PdaNet creates its own Ethernet in network preferences.  This hung around after uninstall.  I deleted it but it did not make a difference.

Any ideas?

Mac OS X 10.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [info page](http://www.junefabrics.com/iphone/mac.php), you need to run a script that will actually remove all the components installed:

> If you ever need to uninstall or before you reinstall PdaNet, please run `~/PdaNetUninstall.sh` in your home directory and reboot.

I'm guessing PDANet installed a daemon that's still around, and that AppZapper missed. It's possible you'll see some errors, since you've removed some of PDANet's components, but try anyway.